# How to connect QItemDelegate (QLineEdit) change to QSortFilterProxyModel PyQt4?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtableview, qitemdelegate

I tried to set a QlineEdit by subclassing QItemDelegate in first row of my QtableView:

```
class ExampleDelegate(QItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        self.line_edit = QLineEdit(parent)
        return self.line_edit

class example(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(druglist, self).__init__()
        self.UI()
    def UI(self):
        self.table_view=QTableView()
        self.delegate = ExampleDelegate()   
        self.table_view.setItemDelegateForColumn(0, self.delegate)
        self.table_model=QStandardItemModel()

        self.table_proxy=QSortFilterProxyModel()
        self.table_proxy.setSourceModel(self.table_model)

        self.table_view.setModel(self.table_proxy)

        self.delegate.textChanged.connect(self.lineedit_textchange) //do something like this

     def lineedit_textchange(self,text):
        search=QRegExp(text,Qt.CaseInsensitive,QRegExp.RegExp)
        self.table_proxy_model.setFilterRegExp(search)
```

I just want to know how could I connect my `ExampleDelegate` text change to my `lineedit_textchange` function in main class?

Answer (score 2):

You should not connect to the `line_edit` in the delegate. The delegate is here to set a custom editor in multiple cells of your `QTableView` (here all the cells in column 0).
If you could connect to the`line_edit` in the delegate, how would you know which cell has been changed ?

What you want is to know when a cell in the column 0 has been changed. Every model has the `dataChanged` signal:

> void QAbstractItemModel::dataChanged(const QModelIndex & topLeft, const QModelIndex & bottomRight)
>
> This signal is emitted whenever the data in an existing item changes.

You can connect to this signal to get the index of a cell that just changed. You can check whether this cell is in column 0, and proceed accordingly:

```
def UI(self):
    self.model=QStandardItemModel(4,2)
    self.model.dataChanged.connect(self.on_dataChanged)

    self.delegate=Delegate()

    self.view=QTableView()
    self.view.setItemDelegateForColumn(0,self.delegate)
    self.view.setModel(self.model)

def on_dataChanged(self,index,index2):
    print(index,index2)
    print(index.data())
    print(index.column())
    if index==index2 and index.column()==0:
        #do stuff
```

Comment: let's be clear,in this pic:http://oi67.tinypic.com/dxxwkk.jpg   i wan to move my search line edit inside the table(an extra cell or field in top of the column).could you tell me please what exactly do i need? i can't find anything from the web

Comment: I believe you have all the informations you need to do what you want, with this answer and your previous question.  Maybe your confused on how to set a delegate for a row instead of a column ?

Comment: the confusing part is giving the delegate change(lineedit text change) to self.table_proxy_model.setFilterRegExp(search) as search

Comment: When the line edit text is changed, `dataChanged` will be emit, with the index of the cell. The text of the line edit is the data of the cell (`index.data()`)

Comment: Ok.but index.data() return all item and i need the first cell (0,0) item to give to my lineedit_textchange() .thanks for spending your time on my issue